# Efficient way in Swift to trim an array

Tags: array, swift

Let's say I have a struct…

```
struct Person {
   let isMale: Bool
   let name: String
}
```

and an array of `Person` structs. I want to trim all the men (`isMale == true`) from the *start* and *end* of the array (similarly to how you'd trim whitespace from the start & end of a string)…

```
func trimMen(people: [Person]) -> [Person]

    var trimmedPeople: [Person] = people

    while trimmedPeople.first?.isMale {
        trimmedPeople.removeFirst()
    }
    while trimmedPeople.last?.isMale {
        trimmedPeople.removeLast()
    }
    return trimmedPeople
}
```

Is there a more efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following implementation provides generic solution, which mimics other foundation methods like `filter`, `map` etc. Though extends `Array` instead of `SequenceType`.

Main benefit from this solution comparing to the [original](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/139442/115718) provided by [Ashley Mills](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/13762/ashley-mills) is that it does not mutate an array.

```
extension Array {

    func trim(@noescape predicate: (Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> [Element] {
        guard let
            start = try (indexOf { try !predicate($0) }),
            end = try (reverse().indexOf { try !predicate($0) }) else {
                return []
        }
        return Array(self[start..<end.base])
    }

}
```

**Usage Example:**

```
persons.trim { $0.isMale }
```

Comment: If the `guard` fails, then you want to return `[]`, not `self` (the guard fails if all elements meet the predicate, thus all should be trimmed). You could also use the half-open range operator instead of the closed range operator (`self[start..<end.base]`). Also `<Element>` can be inferred in the return statement.

Comment: Thanks for noticing guard issue. I knew about closed range operator, but was in a hurry and didn't notice that I can use it.

Comment: Will update my answer soon

Comment: Can you also provide some review of the original code. Alternate solutions without explanation are frowned on, and may not get high scores. See the How to give a good answer on this web page: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer. For example explain why your method is more efficient.

Comment: @pacmaninbw updated

Answer (score 2):

Swift 3.1 has solved this problem with `drop(while:)` and `prefix(while:)`

```
struct Person {
    let isMale: Bool
    let name: String
}

let people = [Person(isMale: true, name: "Bill"),
              Person(isMale: false, name: "Jane"),
              Person(isMale: true, name: "José"),
              Person(isMale: false, name: "Sarah"),
              Person(isMale: true, name: "Steve"),
              Person(isMale: true, name: "Tony")]

func trimMen(people: [Person]) -> [Person] {
    let removedPrefixMen = people.drop { $0.isMale }
    let removedSuffixMen = removedPrefixMen.reversed().drop { $0.isMale }
    return removedSuffixMen.reversed()
}

// [{isMale false, name "Jane"}, {isMale true, name "José"}, {isMale false, name "Sarah"}]
```

Also in Swift 3.1, concrete constrained extensions, means I can do this…

```
extension Array where Element == Person {

    func trimMen() -> [Element] {
        let removedPrefixMen = drop{ $0.isMale }
        let removedSuffixMen = removedPrefixMen.reversed().drop{ $0.isMale }
        return removedSuffixMen.reversed()
    }
}

people.trimMen()
```